Use Lambda to stack multiple query array
I want to stack multiple query result in a single array.
Table 1 to 3 share the same column structure.  In column D, they are either "Y" or "N".  I want to have only the "Y" row to be shown.  My anticipated results are shown below.
SAMPLE SHEET

Table1



A
B
C
D




DIO
DASF
SDFA
Y


SADF
ERT
RWET
N


DGGF
SAF
FDG
Y


DFG
ERT
FXG
Y


FG
DFG
34RW
N



Table2



A
B
C
D




SAF
H
HFH
N


GFH
W
FG
Y


N
GJ
WR
Y


FGH
GG
BNV
N


2WEF
FDG
ZZEAS
N



Table3



A
B
C
D




FAG
HUIO
ERE45
N


YTV3
RTERTY
IO
N


GASFAS
YTUYTUI
UIP
Y


SADFSA
SA
IOP
Y



Anticipated Result



A
B
C
D




DIO
DASF
SDFA
Y


DGGF
SAF
FDG
Y


DFG
ERT
FXG
Y


A
B
C
D


GFH
W
FG
Y


N
GJ
WR
Y


A
B
C
D


GASFAS
YTUYTUI
UIP
Y


SADFSA
SA
IOP
Y



Formula I tried (map lambda), but in vain.
=map({"Table1";"Table2";"Table3"},LAMBDA(colA,arrayformula(vstack(query(indirect(colA),"select * where Col4='Y'")))))
Representative Screenshot



Here's one approach you may test out:
=reduce(tocol(,1),J8:J10,lambda(a,c,vstack(a,query(indirect(c),"Where Col4='Y'",1))))


